# Keeping php sessions after browser is closed

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-variables

I've noticed that when I use tumblr, I never have to log in (unless I have explicitly logged out beforehand). Even if I have closed my browser, shut down my computer, not visited tumblr in like a month if I visit tumblr.com I find that I am still logged in.

How are they accomplishing this? Just setting session_set_cookie_params for like a month or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They use a cookie, with an expire time in the future.

```
setcookie('username','bob',time()+3600*24*7);
```

That would create the username cookie for 7 days.
Notice that if you clear your cookies, you will become logged out of all websites.

Comment: Also, it should be noted: $_SESSION is just a cookie without the 'expire' parameter at 0. You can set a cookie with expire time 0 and when you close your browser, the cookie is deleted.

Comment: So basically I set my session.cookie_lifetime to 604800 in php.ini to have my session cookies last 1 week? Or 2419200 to last a month?

Comment: You really should leave the session.cookie as the default value, since a 'session' is typically done when the browser closes. If at all possible, use a standard cookie to keep track of your logins. http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: BE VERY CAREFUL - (For the record) There is a huge security flaw in doing sessions like this, any user can set their own cookies and appear to be logged in as a user, without every typing in a password. The php $_SESSION doesn't save any data on the users computer, (except a difficult to replicate identifier). If your server is dedicated to a specific web service, do it with $_SESSION anyway.

Answer (score 0):

They are doing this with a cookie. Clear your cookies and you have to log in again.